# MySQL Query Result Image Resize

Tags: php, mysql, image, resize

I am designing a forum.

People post their content which uploaded into my database and then I grab their content using mysql_query(); and then display it using nl2br();

My problem is, if someone inserts a  tag and the image is huge, it will display the image and mess my design up.

So, is there a way I can search the results to see if an  tag is in there, and if so get the size and adjust it if over a set width and height.